# Is there a way to take an id inside a model and use that to create a relation in django?

Tags: python, django

I realized that I should have created a relation in my model, but instead I stored the id.

Is there a way that I can take the id and create a relation with my model object?

For example I have a model defined like this currently:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    user_id= models.IntegerField()
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
...
```

I have 1000+ objects stored in the database with objects like this. Now I want to define the model such that the prexisting model objects get updated with the proper relation according to the id. My model object would look like this and the prexisting objects would have the proper relation :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Service(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User) 
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is. In Django 1.7+, first create a migration with `manage.py makemigration <app_name>`, but don't run it just yet. In your migration you'll find these operations:

```
operations = [
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='service',
        name='user_id',
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='service',
        name='user',
        field=models.ForeignKey(to='auth.User'),
    ),
]
```

This will remove the column and wipe all data, but you don't want that. Instead, you should rename the field and use `AlterField` to add a foreign key constraint:

```
operations = [
    migrations.RenameField(
        model_name='service',
        old_name='user_id',
        new_name='user',
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='service',
        name='user',
        field=models.ForeignKey(to='auth.User'),
    ),
]
```

Now I can only test this on SQLite at the moment, which doesn't force foreign key constraints. On Mysql/PostGRESQL this will probably fail if you have a `user_id` that's not the `id` of a `User`. If that's the case, you'll need to apply a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) first that handles any inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

which version of django?  1.7+ has migrations built in.  You just change your model and do the migration  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/

If you are using an earlier version checkout south.  It does roughly the same thing.

You can also just change your model, then change the table definition directly with sql

Comment: ok, I'll look into this. I'm using 1.7. The thing is when I do my migration I don't want to lose the user_id. I would like the preexisting objects to get updated so that the 'user' field corresponds with the user_id.

Comment: You won't lose anything.  What is your db?

Comment: the db name? it is services_service

Comment: not the name.  Are you using postgres, mysql or sqlite?

Comment: Oh ok. Im using postgres

Comment: Good directions from @knbk.  Another way is to create a new model, syncdb it and then drop into sql and copy all the old table into the new table.